# Watch can't receive notifications when app is open

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm making an app on iWatch recently and found that if I only implement the method :

```
- (void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification withCompletion:(void (^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType))completionHandler
```

for remote notification on watch side(Extension), I can't receive the notification when my app is opening.

Is it normal for such situation? If it is normal for iWatch, will **APNs** send the notification later after the app is close?

Comment: This situation is happened when I'm opening app on watch, not for iPhone side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegate method of **WCSessionDelegate**

> - (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary *)message{
>        NSLog(@"%@",[message objectForKey:@"<<"your key">>"]);   }

Comment: Thanks for answered me question, but my situation is for some reason, I can't add code for iPhone side, is it possible to fix this issue by only adding code in watch side(Extension)?

Comment: No it is not possible you have to add code for both iPhone and iWatch both because as your iPhone is working as a receiver than their should be something like method to receive message. Therefore you can use WCSessionDelegate at both the side.  Have a look on this tutorial. http://www.kristinathai.com/watchos-2-tutorial-using-sendmessage-for-instantaneous-data-transfer-watch-connectivity-1/